# How to unencrypt a micro SD card?

Tags: encryption, android, gparted, sd-card

Few days ago I had to reformat my smartphone (Moto G5 with Android 7.0) but after, I received a very bad surprise when Android put me a message telling me the micro SD card was unreadable because encrypted.

I tried to reformat it but Android could not do it (error message) and I've the same with GParted: it finds the SD card but cannot detect the format and is unable to format it

Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you do not care about the contents, you can use `dd` to overwrite the first few MB of the card with zeroes from `/dev/zero` and then `Gparted` should be able to re-partition. Encrypted may be a red herring, because your card may have developed bad sectors due to flash wear, so this is just a general idea how to proceed when devices cannot work with flash media.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't recover your sd card if you format your phone.
Android stores the encryption key for your sd card in the trust store which is basically erase on factory reset.
You should be able to format your sdcard with gparted but you would need to remove the partition table before and recreate it.
Also sd card are not to be trusted and defective unit are quiet common.

Comment: Is there any way to save the encryption key before formatting?